# Regex to replace @PathVariable values in Spring @RequestMapping URL

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC URL's define in Interfaces (just to hold the Constants) like:

```
String URL_X = "/my-url/{id:[0-9]*}";
String URL_Y = "/my-url/{id:[0-9]*}/blah-blah";
```

I have a method for my tests that replace the variables in an URL:

```
private static final String REGEX_PARAMETROS_DA_URL = "(\\{[^\\}]*\\})";
    protected String replaceParametersOnURL(String urlSpring, String... params) {
        String urlAtual = urlSpring;
        for (String parametro : params) {
            urlAtual = urlAtual.replaceFirst(REGEX_PARAMETROS_DA_URL, parametro);
        }
        return urlAtual;
    }
```

I was using this regex: `(\{[^\}]*\})` to match the variables and replace it.
But now i have some URL's that have {} on it and i can't find a properly regex to replace the variable with my value.

Is there any method on Spring that replaces the PathVariable value or can anyone help me with this regex?

Given this URL for instance:

```
/pessoajuridica/{cnpj:[0-9]{14}}-{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}/sancoes/resumo
```

The matches must be: `{cnpj:[0-9]{14}}`and `{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}`

Comment: have you took a look at the spring mvc test docs [server performing request](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server-performing-requests)

Comment: @Thomas this solves this specifica problem, but if i found a more complex regex like {cnpj:[0-9]{14}[a-Z]} it will not work! =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Matthew. I haven't noticed that the spring test itself can do this!

All i need to do is:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/pessoajuridica/{cnpj:[0-9]{14}}-{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}/sancoes/resumo", var1, var2)) ...
```